# How to autopopulate a text box in html and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a page where a new user can input a username pswrd ect. then they fill out some information. An admin can then go and see whos registered and If so desired can go and edit the information entered by the user. What happens is when the admin clicks a button that redirects them to the schedule page I want the text fields to already be populated with all the information. I have confirmed with echo statements that I do have all the correct information at button press, I just cant get the text fields to update when the page loads.

Here is an example of one of the text boxes

```
<input type="text" id = "textBoxSchedule" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email?>" required>
```

I have correctly set the value of $email, but what my guess is, is that HTML runs, creates the text box and then the PHP runs so its set after the value is created.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: 
Ok so heres how I get the information. From the admin page, I know what user I want to edit. So I pass that user name value through the $_SESSION variable and then I can use that one piece of information to get the rest of the text fields. Im not sure if this will have an affect or if its something I can utalize but the text boxes are below a header of:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method = "post">
```

(im partner coding this and he wrote a majority of this so im still working on understanding it all.)

Comment: FYI, the PHP is executed before it ever makes it to a user's computer so thinking that the HTML is rendered and then the PHP is executed is just simply wrong.

Comment: var dump $email to see what it returns

Comment: SHow us all the code. Specially the code that loads `$email` ___Otherwise we can only make guesses___

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you may be missing ; after $email

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript for it.

```
<input type="text" id = "textBoxSchedule" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>

<?php echo "<script>myFunction(".$email."); </script>" ?>
```

The JS is ~

```
myFunction(x){
document.getElementById('textBoxSchedule').value = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll post an answer

```
<?php echo $email?>
```

You forgot the semicolon ( ; ) and you didn't leave a space before ?>

Also although it's not false, you should not put spaces before and after = symbol in html attributes

```
id = "textBoxSchedule"
```

Lastly I presume you reload the page and you don't expect php to run in client's browser?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tested your script on a blank php page with the following code:

```
<?php
  $email = "test@email.com";
?>
<input type="text" id = "textBoxSchedule" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email?>" required>
```

And I’ve managed to get the text box showing properly.

If you still have a problem showing your text box, you might want to double check the value of your $email variable of the code prior and after the example you’ve given us.